# Asterisk 3 way calling with IVR

Tags: asterisk

I'm using asterisk 1.4 
 
when my agent talks with customer , we need a option of putting their call in a IVR 
in which agent and customer can listen those ivr menu at a same time , eventually customer should send some DTMF for IVR menus 
Could any one pls tell me in what way we can achieve this

Comment: This link will help you http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+n-way+call+HOWTO It have examples of n-way calling, most via conference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider dropping both calling and called parties (customer & agent, respective to how you're operating) into a conference call, and then!

...Go and originate another call (with AMI or a call file) that's operating from a new context/extension/proirity and also drop this originated call into the conference.

I haven't tested this with DTMF input into a call prompt -- But, I have played automated messages to both calling and called party in a conference using this technique.

The caveat may be that both calling and called parties will have control of the prompt. Which may or not be relevant to your use case.

Comment: sounds like a great idea!!!! , but in my case I originate the call and bridged with the customer , can we put a bridged call in to a meetme queue ???

Comment: can u pls tell me how would u play automated messages , can u pls post some sample snippets

Comment: how can i originate a call, if i originate then it would ring for some sip client isnt it , I must originate an anonymous call which have to fall in dialplan